# Python: Substracting between list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, delta

I have 2 list containing dictionaries as follows:

```
listone = [{'unit1': {'test1': 10}}, 
           {'unit1': {'test2': 45'}, 
           {'unit2': {'test1': 78'}, 
           {'unit2': {'test2': 2'}}]

listtwo = [{'unit1': {'test1': 56}}, 
           {'unit1': {'test2': 34'}, 
           {'unit2': {'test1': 23'}, 
           {'unit2': {'test2': 5'}}]
```

I also do have all the unit names & test-names in separate lists:

```
units = ['unit1', 'unit2']
testnames = ['test1,'test2']
```

How could I find the delta for each test value, i.e. val of (`test2` - `test1`), so that I could finally arrange the data as follows:

```
unit1, test1, delta
unit1, test2, delta
unit2, test1, delta
unit2, test2, delta
```

So far, I have these:

```
def delta(array1, array2):
        temp = []
        temp2 = []
        tmp = []
        tmp2 = []
        delta = []
        for unit in units:
            for mkey in array1:
                for skey in mkey:
                    if skey == unit:
                        temp.append(mkey[skey])
                        floater(temp) #floats all the values
                        for i in testnames:
                            for u in temp:
                                tmp.append(u[i])
                                tmp = filter(None, tmp2)

            for mkey in array2:
                for skey in mkey:
                    if skey == unit:
                        temp.append(mkey[skey])
                        floater(temp2)
                        for i in testnames:
                            for u in temp2:
                                tmp2.append(u[i])
                                tmp2 = filter(None, tmp2)

        delta = [tmp2 - tmp for tmp2, tmp in zip(tmp2, tmp)] 
        print delta

delta(listone,listtwo)
```

Unfortunately, the code gives `Keyerror`. :(
Help, please. Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *delta of each test value*. Can you elablorate? Perhaps give a concrete example.

Comment: delta means the substraction. i.e. output should be: unit1, test1, 46 ; unit1, test2, -11; ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar but a bit more encapsulated:

```
from collections import defaultdict

listone = [
    {'unit1': {'test1': 10}},
    {'unit1': {'test2': 45}}, 
    {'unit2': {'test1': 78}}, 
    {'unit2': {'test2': 2}}
]

listtwo = [
    {'unit1': {'test1': 56}},
    {'unit1': {'test2': 34}}, 
    {'unit2': {'test1': 23}}, 
    {'unit2': {'test2': 5}}
]

def dictify(lst):
    res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for entry in lst:
        for unit,testentry in entry.iteritems():
            for test,val in testentry.iteritems():
                res[unit][test] = val
    return res
    # returns dict['unitX']['testY'] = val

def genDeltas(dictA, dictB):
    units = dictA.keys()
    units.sort()
    tests = dictA[units[0]].keys()
    tests.sort()
    for unit in units:
        _A = dictA[unit]
        _B = dictB[unit]
        for test in tests:
            yield unit,test,(_B[test]-_A[test])

for unit,test,delta in genDeltas(dictify(listone),dictify(listtwo)):
    print "{0}, {1}, {2}".format(unit,test,delta)
```

**Edit:** to find field-averages:

```
class Avg(object):
    def __init__(self, total=0.0, num=0):
        super(Avg,self).__init__()
        self.total = total
        self.num   = num

    def add(self, value):
        self.total += value
        self.num   += 1

    def value(self):
        return self.total / self.num

def avgBy(data, field=0):
    res = defaultdict(Avg)
    for unit,testdict in data.iteritems():
        for test,val in testdict.iteritems():
            res[(unit,test)[field]].add(val)
    return {item:avg.value() for item,avg in res.iteritems()}

dictone = dictify(listone)
avg_by_unit = avgBy(dictone, 0)
print(avg_by_unit)
avg_by_test = avgBy(dictone, 1)
print(avg_by_test)
```

Comment: thanks! .. though the last print line gave error.. worked around it. i was reading the defaultdict module, but didnt know how to use it. thanks for the example.

Comment: @siva: works as-is for me (Python 2.7.1); for Python 3, print is a function, not a statement, and must be enclosed in brackets, ie print("abc").

Comment: Im trying out how to work with single dictified dict. i.e. to find max, min, avg of the 'units' by 'tests' in the dict. How do we iterate through the 'tests' first instead of the 'units', as i get unit referenced before assignt error...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps convert your data to a different, more convenient data structure.
For example, instead of `listone`, it would be easier to work with a single dict like this:

```
{('unit1', 'test1'): 10,
 ('unit2', 'test1'): 78,
 ('unit2', 'test2'): 2,
 ('unit1', 'test2'): 45}
```

So given,

```
import itertools
units = ['unit1', 'unit2']
testnames = ['test1','test2']
listone = [{'unit1': {'test1': 10}}, 
           {'unit1': {'test2': 45}}, 
           {'unit2': {'test1': 78}}, 
           {'unit2': {'test2': 2}}]

listtwo = [{'unit1': {'test1': 56}}, 
           {'unit1': {'test2': 34}}, 
           {'unit2': {'test1': 23}}, 
           {'unit2': {'test2': 5}}]
```

Here we convert `listone` and `listtwo` to a list of dicts:

```
dicts=[{},{}]
for i,alist in enumerate([listone,listtwo]):
    for item in alist:
        for unit,testdict in item.iteritems():
            for testname,value in testdict.iteritems():
                dicts[i][unit,testname]=value
```

Now finding the `deltas` is easy:

```
for unit,testname in itertools.product(units,testnames):
    delta=dicts[1][unit,testname]-dicts[0][unit,testname]
    print('{u}, {t}, {d}'.format(u=unit,t=testname,d=delta))
```

yields

```
unit1, test1, 46
unit1, test2, -11
unit2, test1, -55
unit2, test2, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier done with dictionaries of dictionaries. Here, I define them in steps, since I assume you're gathering the results from some testing process, but you can also do it in one line.

```
listOne = {}
listOne['unit1'] = {}
listOne['unit2'] = {}
listOne['unit1']['test1']=10
listOne['unit1']['test2']=45
listOne['unit2']['test1'] = 78
listOne['unit2']['test2'] = 2

listTwo = {}
listTwo['unit1'] = {}
listTwo['unit2'] = {}
listTwo['unit1']['test1']=56
listTwo['unit1']['test2']=34
listTwo['unit2']['test1'] = 23
listTwo['unit2']['test2'] = 5

units = ['unit1', 'unit2']
testnames = ['test1','test2']

deltas = {}

# collect the deltas
for unit in units :
    deltas[unit] = {}
    for test in testnames :
        deltas[unit][test] = listTwo[unit][test] -listOne[unit][test]

# print put the results
for unit in units :
    for test in testnames :
        print unit, ', ', test, ', ', deltas[unit][test]
```

This yields

```
unit1 ,  test1 ,  46
unit1 ,  test2 ,  -11
unit2 ,  test1 ,  -55
unit2 ,  test2 ,  3
```

Comment: if I have the dictionaries stored in the list, how do u iterate into two list at the same time to access the corresponding dicts from each list? something like... for [dict1, dict2] in {listOne, listTwo]: find deltas.. thanks too. helpful

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What do you have, and what do you need? A list of two dicts, plus the four keys 'unit1', 'unit2', 'test1', 'test2', and you need some kind of structure with <unit>, <test>, <delta>? If so, the "collect the ddeltas" above can be modified to provide the structure you need. I don't think it is necessary to iterate over two lists...

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your current problem:

```
listone = [{'unit1': {'test1': 10}}, 
    {'unit1': {'test2': 45}}, 
    {'unit2': {'test1': 78}}, 
       {'unit2': {'test2': 2}}]

listtwo = [{'unit1': {'test1': 56}}, 
    {'unit1': {'test2': 34}}, 
    {'unit2': {'test1': 23}}, 
           {'unit2': {'test2': 5}}]

units = ['unit1', 'unit2']
testnames = ['test1', 'test2']


# Iterate over all units
for unit in units:
    # Iterate over all tests
    for test in testnames:
        # Find the rows corresponding to our current unit/test
        list1Row = [i for i,d in enumerate(listone) if d.keys()[0] == unit and d.values()[0].keys()[0] == test]
        list2Row = [i for i,d in enumerate(listtwo) if d.keys()[0] == unit and d.values()[0].keys()[0] == test]

        # Check to make sure there was exactly one match.
        # This is another weakness of your data structure.
        if (len(list1Row) == 1) and (len(list2Row) == 1):
            list1Row = list1Row[0]
            list2Row = list2Row[0]
            delta = listtwo[list2Row].values()[0].values()[0] - listone[list1Row].values()[0].values()[0]
            print unit, test, delta
```

However, as the previous poster recommended, you should really consider a different data structure.  I would suggest something like a single dictionary with a (unit, test) key and a list value.